# AWS Elastic Inference, Tensorflow 2 - Accelerator Doesn't have Variable Support, Exiting

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to use the [Elastic Inference](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/elastic-inference/) mechanism from AWS. And I have Tensorflow 2 models. When I try to use Elastic Inference with TensorFlow Serving or with TensorFlow Keras API as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastic-inference/latest/developerguide/ei-tensorflow-python.html), I get the same error `Accelerator Doesn't have Variable Support` on both occasions.

```
ubuntu@xx-xxx-xx-0-xxx:~/tensorflow-serving-2-0-0-ei-1-5$ ./amazonei_tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 --model_name=testm --model_base_path=/home/ubuntu/testm
2021-01-26 19:37:28.781844: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:85] Building single TensorFlow model file config:  model_name: testm model_base_path: /home/ubuntu/testm
2021-01-26 19:37:28.782019: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:462] Adding/updating models.                                                                                                  
2021-01-26 19:37:28.782044: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:573]  (Re-)adding model: testm                                                                                               
2021-01-26 19:37:28.882449: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:739] Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: testm version: 1}
2021-01-26 19:37:28.882485: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for servable version {name: testm version: 1}
2021-01-26 19:37:28.882497: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version {name: testm version: 1}
2021-01-26 19:37:28.882524: I external/ei_for_tf/ei_for_tf/util/saved_model_util.h:75] Reading SavedModel from: /home/ubuntu/testm/1
2021-01-26 19:37:28.940140: I external/ei_for_tf/ei_for_tf/util/saved_model_util.h:98] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2021-01-26 19:37:29.069412: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: /home/ubuntu/testm/1
2021-01-26 19:37:29.103278: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2021-01-26 19:37:29.169323: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX512F
2021-01-26 19:37:29.358026: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:202] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
Using Amazon Elastic Inference Client Library Version: 1.7.0                       
Number of Elastic Inference Accelerators Available: 1                
Elastic Inference Accelerator ID: eia-926d6d89ee644dc19d0ada17fcbd423d                                                                                               
Elastic Inference Accelerator Type: eia2.medium                                                                                                              
Elastic Inference Accelerator Ordinal: 0                                                                                                                         
                                                                
[Tue Jan 26 19:37:41 2021, 810560us] [Execution Engine] Error getting application context for [TensorFlow][2]
[Tue Jan 26 19:37:41 2021, 810620us] [Execution Engine][TensorFlow][2] Failed - Last Error:
    EI Error Code: [1, 14, 36]                                     
    EI Error Description: Service not available. Please wait for sometime. Also, make sure the EI setup is correct. Quick setup instructions - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/launch-ei-accelerators-in-minutes-wit
h-the-amazon-elastic-inference-setup-tool-for-ec2. Setup validation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastic-inference/latest/developerguide/ei-troubleshooting.html#ei-activation
    EI Request ID:   --  EI Accelerator ID: eia-926d6d89ee644dc19d0ada17fcbd423d                                                                                     
    EI Client Version: 1.7.0                                                                                                                                 
2021-01-26 19:37:41.810700: E external/ei_for_tf/ei_for_tf/graph_optimizer/ei_graph_optimizer.cc:114] Accelerator Doesn't have Variable Support, Exiting
```

I'm using the **amazonei-tensorflow** libraries from this [s3 repo](https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/amazonei-tensorflow?region=us-east-1&tab=objects).

The machine I think is well set up to use Elastic inference because when I run the EISetupValidator script as advised [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastic-inference/latest/developerguide/ei-troubleshooting.html). It passes successfully.

```
ubuntu@xx-xxx-xx-x-xxx:~$ python EISetupValidator.py 
All the validation checks passed for Amazon EI from this instance - i-0ec6f6b0899198c0b
```

I'm not finding other references about this error on the internet. I'd appreciate any help or clues. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from the Aws support as put bellow:

> The error "Accelerator Doesn't have Variable Support, Exiting" can be
> ignored if it is preceded by a connectivity error. As the prior error
> indicates the problem seems to be with the EI setup.
>
> For further information on EI error codes:
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastic-inference/latest/developerguide/ei-error-codes.html

Checking again the instructions. My problem was that I didn't attach the right **Security group** to the **VPC Endpoint** created for the Accelerator instance. After adjusting it, the Elastic Inferece worked!